# How to accomplish a rebind and/or implement event handler in Outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, exchange-server, outlook-addin

I have created an Outlook 2013 Add-In in which I would like to update what is displayed in the FROM field, i.e. the sender.  Within my event handler, ThisAddIn_Startup(),AI add another event handler, Application.NewMailEx += Application_NewMail_Ex. Within this event handler, Application_NewMail_Ex(), I am setting the following properties:

```
void Application_NewMailEx(string entryId)
{
    object item = this.Session.GetItemFromID(entryId);
    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)item;
    String contactInfo = getContact(mailItem);  // gets the property I want...
    mailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(PR_SENDER_NAME, contactInfo);
    mailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_NAME, contactInfo);
}
```

This ALMOST works perfectly, BUT this is what I am observing:

1. In my main Outlook window, in the list of emails (list view?), when a new email comes in, it **DOES NOT** display the intended **contactInfo** upon first view, e.g. let's say my cursor is on  another line item.
2. When I do **CLICK** on that new email from the list view of emails, it is now SELECTED and the preview pane (towards the bottom half) **DOES** show the correct **contactInfo**.
3. When I **DOUBLE-CLICK** on that same email, when the email loads up as a new window, the FROM address **DOES** show the correct **contactInfo**.
4. When I move to another email within the main Outlook window of emails (list view?), previously **SELECTED** email **DOES** show now the correct **contactInfo** in the FROM field.

How can I solve #4?

What other events should I be concerned with?

Do I have to do some kind of rebinding?

Also, how do I solve the issue with emails that are already in my **Inbox**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call MailItem.Save to make sure the changes are committed.